# If i use youtube v3 api and watch videos then i get watch-time count?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, youtube, android-youtube-api

If I use YouTube API v3 in my Android app and people watch videos of my YouTube channel from my Android app then those watch-time add to my YouTube channel watch-time?